# Select Multiple MySql Rows according to ID From Array list - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to select multiple rows by querying a mysql database from an array of IDs fetched from another database, but i seem to be having no luck, i retrieve the ID's then store them in an array set like this; $array = results=> followerID=> "1", "2".
i can't seem to loop through the nested arrays results aswell as being able to use them to search the database and display all the results returned.

UPDATE:

$ids var_dump:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["followingID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["followingID"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["followingID"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
$user = $_REQUEST['userID'];
$userNID = $_REQUEST['user'];


$check = query("SELECT followingID FROM user_follows WHERE followerID='%s'", $user);

if (count($check['result'])>0) {
    $ids = $check['result'];
    $id_implode = implode( "', '", $ids);

    echo '{"implode":'.$id_implode.'}';

    $get = query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM user_accounts WHERE userID IN ('%s')", $id_implode);
if (!$get['error']) {

    class Emp {
       public $success = "";
       public $result = "";
       public $error = "";
    }
    $e = new Emp();
    $e->success = 1;
    $e->result = $get['result'];
    $e->error = "No problems";

    echo json_encode($e);

    } else {


    class Emp {
       public $success = "";
       public $error = "";
    }
    $e = new Emp();
    $e->success = 0;
    $e->error = "Connection Error";

    echo json_encode($e);
    exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what's the query that this outputs? as in, what happens when you print $get ?

Comment: At the moment it comes back empty, i think it has something to do with not retreiving the nested array inside $check['result'], it would be $check['result'][Int]['followingID'], but i can't loop through to get the ID's to then query

Comment: can you var_dump($ids);  to find out is id is actually containing some values? if yes tell me what the values output is like

Comment: Gave you an answer which hopefully should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks for the update this should help you fix your code:

place this after setting the $ids variable

```
$id_holder = array();

foreach($ids as $key=>$value){
    array_push($id_holder,$value['followingID']);
}

$id_holder = implode(',',$id_holder);
```

Then the rest of your code.

Comment: Ok that worked, but the issue i thought i would also have is then using that array query all the contact details that go with those ID's, at the moment its only fetching the first one in the list

Comment: So i've just retrieved the array of userID's, now i would like to select rows from another database where those userID's exist, i thought using WHERE IN Would work, but it only pulls the first the info for the first userID

Comment: oh ok i think i know why. give me a sec am updating my answer

Comment: I think i see what i did wrong, i used $get = query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM user_accounts WHERE userID IN ($id_holder)"); instead of using $get = query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM user_accounts WHERE userID IN ('%s')", $id_holder); and it worked